# Spring + hibernate tables are not generated

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

my tables are not being generated and I'm feeling that I'm missing something obvious. MySQL is used and all the properties are correctly mapped to the session factory.

As far as I know, it should work given these settings, right? Am I missing some property?

**application.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dc_comp?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = 0
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true

spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

**com.example.springmvc.configuration.HibernateConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"com.example.springmvc.configuration"})
@EntityScan({"com.example.springmvc.model"})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(hibernateDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.example.springmvc.model"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        sessionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource hibernateDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("spring.jpa.generate-ddl", environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.generate-ddl"));

        properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

**com.example.springmvc.model.Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

The good parts of the log. This may indicate something wrong with the session factory?

```
11:18:01.908 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dc_comp?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]
11:18:02.068 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - Database ->
       name : MySQL
    version : 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
      major : 5
      minor : 7
11:18:02.068 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - Driver ->
       name : MySQL Connector Java
    version : mysql-connector-java-5.1.44 ( Revision: b3cda4f864902ffdde495b9df93937c3e20009be )
      major : 5
      minor : 1
...
11:18:02.152 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Namespace - Created database namespace [logicalName=Name{catalog=null, schema=null}, physicalName=Name{catalog=null, schema=null}]
11:18:02.169 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.example.springmvc.model.Employee
11:18:02.188 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3DiscriminatorColumn{logicalColumnName'DTYPE', discriminatorTypeName='string'}
11:18:02.193 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Import with entity name Employee
...
11:18:02.195 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.example.springmvc.model.Employee on table EMPLOYEE
11:18:02.218 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(EMPLOYEE), mappingColumn=id, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
11:18:02.221 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - MetadataSourceProcessor property id with lazy=false
11:18:02.223 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder - Attempting to locate auto-apply AttributeConverter for property [com.example.springmvc.model.Employee:id]
11:18:02.225 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - building SimpleValue for id
11:18:02.227 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Building property id
11:18:02.230 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(EMPLOYEE), mappingColumn=NAME, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
11:18:02.230 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - MetadataSourceProcessor property name with lazy=false
11:18:02.230 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder - Attempting to locate auto-apply AttributeConverter for property [com.example.springmvc.model.Employee:name]
11:18:02.231 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - building SimpleValue for name
11:18:02.231 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Building property name
...
11:18:02.240 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - Starting fillSimpleValue for id
11:18:02.240 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - Starting fillSimpleValue for name
...
11:18:02.241 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.mapping.PrimaryKey - Forcing column [id] to be non-null as it is part of the primary key for table [employee]
...
11:34:55.533 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - SessionFactory name : null
...
11:34:55.570 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl - Returning a Reference to the SessionFactory
11:34:55.571 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl - Session factory constructed with filter configurations : {}
11:34:55.571 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl - Instantiating session factory with properties: {java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, ...
...
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'dc_comp.EMPLOYEE' doesn't exist
```

Been stuck on this for a couple hours now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

CX

Comment: Did you try <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> or <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>

Comment: @hurricane Yes, there's `spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true` and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update` in my `application.properties`, which are read at set into the hibernate properties in the method `HibernateConfiguration.hibernateProperties` which are then set into the session factory `sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());`

Comment: I think you need to use this : `properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));`

Comment: @hurricane This solved my issue, for some reason, `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` wouldn't work and I had to use the hibernate property directly, like you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If your tables do not currently exist and you want Spring/Hibernate to create them on start up you need to change
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update` to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create`
For more information: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: Both options were already present in application.properties, but `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` wouldn't stick for some reason. Replacing it with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` solved my issue.

Comment: I think the spring.jpa.hibernate version is used to configure when Spring Boot is used. If Spring Boot is not used you use the standard hibernate properties as you have stated above.